# Why aren't these buttons deleting the rows that contain them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What I'm trying to do with the following snippet should be self-explanatory

```
    <tbody id="slide-table-body">
    </tbody>                            
</table>
<button class="wp-core-ui button-primary" type="button" onclick="addAnotherSlide()">Add another carousel item</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var newRowHtml = '<tr><td>(assetprevurl)</td><td>(asseturl)</td><td><button type="button" class="wp-core-ui button-primary deleteSlideButton">Delete Slide</button></td></tr>';

      function addAnotherSlide() { jQuery('#slide-table-body').append(newRowHtml); }

      jQuery(function($){
           $('.deleteSlideButton').click(function() { $(this).closest('tr').remove();});
</script>
```

My problem is that

```
$('.deleteSlideButton').click(function() { $(this).closest('tr').remove();} );
```

isn't deleting the row and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Please take the time to format your code better in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're adding the html after the DOM is loaded, try using Jquery **on** :

```
$( ".deleteSlideButton" ).on( "click", function() {
      console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: It probably has to do with the way you're traversing the DOM to try to remove(). It's not clear whether you're trying to delete the current <tr> it's on or some sibling. Either way, closest() is probably causing you problems as it's not very specific.

This might guide you in the right direction: http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/traversing-manipulating

Answer (score 0):

It's cause you've attached an event handler to a newly created DOM element. Change it to:

```
$('.deleteSlideButton').on("click", function() {
  // do something
});
```

This may also help: [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)